# Mod_rewrite /category.htm into /category

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

After all those mod rewrite topics here at stackoverflow, I still haven't find an answer to my question. I have a topsite, and basically all I want to do is to change **/index.php?method=in&cat=Half+Life** (the "+" is a space) into **/Half-Life** .

Until now, I've succeeded changing **/index.php?method=in&cat=Half+Life** into **/Half+Life.htm** .

What I want is to make the .htm disappear and to change the ***"+"*** into ***"-"***.

Here's my code with what I'm working on in my .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.htm$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

One more question: Is it more, how should I call it, "SEO-friendly", if I do it this way?

Thanks!

Comment: i would recommend to use `-` and not `+` like: `/game/half-life/` so when you call (in your anchor) use dashes intead

Comment: Well, that's what I want to do in .htaccess with mod_rewrite. I bet it's possible to change the spaces, I mean the "+" in the links, but I do not know how.

Comment: sorry to ask this, but why in .htaccess? that link must be referenced somewhere else no? maybe im not following your flow/process

Comment: Why in .htaccess? Well, this is the only way I know it can be done. And the links of the categories are included on the front page. This is my website, and those are my categories on the left side of the page : http://games-top200.com/

Comment: I would change on the URL then in php or python change it to the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with removing the .htm from it is that it then rewrites every single url.   That would include urls for files that actually exist (like index.php). There are a couple approaches that you could take.

Assume that all your actual files have a dot (.) in the file name, rewrite everything else.  If you do actually have files or directories that are named without an extension, this won't work.  Or if you want some of your categories to have dots.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

You can have your rewrite rule ignore files that actually exist

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. The only thing that remained is to change the "+" into "-".

This is how is now : http://games-top200.com/Gaming+Websites
And this is how I'd like it to be. It doesn't show the same info, although that the page works, take a look : http://games-top200.com/Gaming-Websites

Comment: I'm going to check it anyhow, but have you got any clue on how to change the "+" into "-" ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using your second section of code
`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?cat=$1 [L]`

Comment: The +s are url encoded spaces.  In index.php, if there is a space in cat, then replace it with a - and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to change the php to replace the dashes with spaces, but if you really want to use htaccess:

```
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)\.(htm)$ "$1 $2.$3"
RewriteRule (.*)\.htm$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't know what else I should use. I heard Google indexes the pages faster this way, and that's why I'd like to use .htaccess. By the way, how can I leave the ".htm"? Or is it even possible?

Comment: What do you mean with 'leave the .htm'? My code still does the same as your, except it replaces spaces with dashes.

Answer (score -1):

What you seem to be asking is to translate SEO-style URIs to internal parameter based ones.  Unfortunately, the rewrite engine doesn't support global substitution so you need to cludge this, for example:

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule (\w+)$              index.php?cat=$1       [L]
RewriteRule (\w+)+(\w+)$        index.php?cat=$1-$2    [L]
RewriteRule (\w+)+(\w+)+(\w+)$  index.php?cat=$1-$2-$3 [L]
# and so on ..
```

But the easiest way to do this is to use a general catch all:

```
RewriteRule ([-+\w]+)$              index.php?cat=$1       [L]
```

And use a `str_replace` or `preg_replace` on your `$_GET['cat']` inside your `inddex.php`.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new at php, so this is going to be a bit hard. But thanks!